# How to update Runtime scale monitoring setting in Azure function using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I am using Azure function hosted in premium plan. I want to enable runtime scale monitoring using ARM template.

Screenshot is attached for setting.

[image]

Please suggest how can I enable this setting via ARM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the "Learn More" link in your screenshot it will take you to a doc that describes how to do it via CLI.  That command is setting a property in web config named `functionsRuntimeScaleMonitoringEnabled` to true.  So in your template you would do the same.  How depends a bit on how your template is setting config -- it could be on the webApp itself or on a child resource of type `Microsoft.Web/sites/config`.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
    "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
    "name": "foo",
    "location": "...",
    "properties": {
        "...": "...",
        "functionsRuntimeScaleMonitoringEnabled": true
    }
}
```

Note that ARM is declarative so you can't use that example literally as it will wipe all of your other settings.  You need to fill in the `...` accordingly.

That help?